# How to fit div on responsive background

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently, im looking for a way to do this:

I have some html which holds background image. This image is responsive / it scales on resize thanks to `background-size: cover;` rule.
But in this Html (with `position: relative` rule) i have some div which should have width, height and position to cover one of laptops (in my image top image)

The problem is that even if i use percentages or vw or vh rules, after resize this element will never fit one on laptops (on image screen 2 and 3).

So my question is - is this possible ? If yes i can use every technique possible (javascript, css3) to archive this effect. Also, div should also change dimensions to fit one of laptops.

Thanks for advice.[image]

background size 100% 100% can will squash image.
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a grid layout?

Comment: Not excatly. Laptops are background image not html elements. But div should be positioned "on this grid let's say..."

Comment: Then why don't you just give that div the background image?..

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `%` for `background-size` property

**Example:**

```
div{
   background-size:100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

You can also try `background-attachment` property

Here is the details about [CSS3 background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/css3_pr_background-size.asp) Property

Comment: I've uploaded second image - you can see that patops are suqasher for some resolutions and this looks bad. It's why i can't use this solution.

Comment: You should `crop` the image for perfect view/thumbnail. But I suggest to use `img` tag for displaying image. Don't use `background-image` @user3573535

Comment: I added second answer, Without background image. You can try like as this. @user3573535

Answer (score 0):

**You can try your Gallery like as this** (Without Using Background Image)

```css
ul{
 list-style: none;
}
ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
ul li img{
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
 -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
 transition: all .5s ease;
}
ul li img:hover{
 transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Demo"></li>
 <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Demo"></li>
 <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Demo"></li>
 <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Demo"></li>
 <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Demo"></li>
 <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Demo"></li>
 <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Demo"></li>
 <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Demo"></li>
 <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Demo"></li>
 <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Demo"></li>
 <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Demo"></li>
 <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="Demo"></li>
</ul>
```